# Change home folders after changing language in Gnome 3 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, language-support

After the language is changed from English to another language in Gnome 3 it will ask if you want to change all your home folders. This box you get when you logout and login again to the session. I have changed the language from English to Dutch. Is there any way on command line to avoid this message and always keep the existing English folders? There is also a checkbox "Don't ask this again".

This is the message after changing from English to Dutch:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the file `~/.config/user-dirs.locale`.

```
rm ~/.config/user-dirs.locale
```

(That's what happens if you check the "Don't ask this again" option.)